# Footnotes within longtabu X column appear out of order

Tags: footnotes, tabu

In the following example, the footnotes appear at the bottom of the page in the order 2, 4, 1, 3 (instead of sequentially):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu}{l X}
1\footnote{Footnote 1} & 2\footnote{Footnote 2} \\
3\footnote{Footnote 3} & 4\footnote{Footnote 4}
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

The issue goes away

- if I use a `tabu` environment instead of `longtabu`,
- if neither column is an `X` column, or
- if both columns are `X` columns.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use of the package `tabu`  is not recommended. It is not maintained and buggy. Rather use `tabularx` instead of `tabu` or `xltabular` instead of `longtabu`. With `tabularx` you will obtain expected result: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
1\footnote{Footnote 1} & 2\footnote{Footnote 2} \\
3\footnote{Footnote 3} & 4\footnote{Footnote 4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Zarko My understanding is that `tabularx` doesn't support automatic page breaks the way the `longtabu` environment does. Am I mistaken? And if not, what workaround is there?

Comment: Xltabular combines the features of tabularx and longtable.

Comment: @skiasaurus, I said in comment that instead of `longtabu` you can (is better to) use `xltabular`, which combine `tabularx` and `longtable` features.

Comment: @Zarko Using `xltabular` does not solve the problem for me using the latest versions from TeX Live 2020.

Comment: @Martin, and what is your problem? I suggest you to ask new question with an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. Now we are on level of guessing and also rare people see your comment, so probability for receive an answer is very low.

Comment: @Zarko As you wrote, that using `xltabular` instead of `longtabu` fixes the problem, but it does not, I thought, that would be worth a comment. I raised an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/rolfn/xltabular/issues/13).

Comment: BTW: The MWE you asked for is the same one as in the original question, but of course using `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l X}` instead of `\begin{longtabu}` (and using the corresponding package obviously). That's why I was surprised to see it not working after having read your comment.

Comment: @Martin, it works as expected if all columns in table are of `X` type. In a case of the mixed columns, the problem mentioned in question, persist.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree.